# User prompting - Best practice

Tags: user-interface, user-controls

We have been working on developing a web application and I am currently researching best practice for user prompts. We are currently using standard system prompts witch works well but  the issue I heave with this is when a user is prompted that an operation was successful the user has to click the ok button to progress. This can become very irritating if the user has to repeat an action many times.

My question is this, what is the best way to prompt users? To let them know an action was successful and they can move on? I googled it but can not find anything that seems really cool/cutting edge.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a good question for the User Experience Stackexchange site: http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you Colin. Posting it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid dialogs at all costs -- they interrupt flow and are generally considered bad practice from a usability standpoint. All you do with dialogs is train users to automatically click on them without reading, so when you really, *really* do need to show a dialog there's a good chance they will automatically dismiss it without reading.

Instead, put a banner or some other notification on the next page.

Remember: your goal is to make the user productive. Anything you add that takes away from that is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, I see where you coming from. It is very easy to fall into the habit of just dismissing dialogs if you see them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a hidden div that passively displays when the user has completed a checkpoint or process but doesn't not require them to click an "ok" button"

You could have the div then fade away when the next page is loaded or fadeaway based on an elapsed time.